# Facebook integratrion in Android

Tags: android, web-services, facebook

I am new to Android and i have a doubt regarding facebook integration.
Is it possible to integrate Facebook in our application without adding fbrocket or github in our application and writing our own libraries?
Anyone there, please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Comment: ok but any other way like writing our own libraries. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes of course, but you will need an API to access Facebook. And this is it.

Comment: Isn't it possible to write them widout the given API

Comment: How would you access the data then?

Comment: Official Android SDk just wraps this API: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/

Comment: by writing our own classes and is there any specific URL of the facebook where the data of all the users is stored and we can get that data by json parsing....

Comment: Data of all the users? Do you honestly believe Facebook would just provide it's whole data for download?

Comment: no... there are some specific fields which it provides right? so will there be any specific URL to get those particular fields of all the users....

Comment: You do realize that you need to be logged in and people need to accept you as a friend in order for you to see their data?

Comment: BTW, Graph API is just URLs with JSON data.. It's just not the "data of all the users", but only data for specific user.

Comment: ya i have used that for some specific fields of a particular user.

Comment: but now my problem is that i want a URL which contains data of all the users... Is there any URL like that? Do you think there will be any URL like that?

Comment: No. I don't think this is in the interest of Facebook. IMHO it will never exist.